# Insertar una tabla HTML a MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Buen día. Estoy haciendo un desarrollo para insertar unos datos de una tabla en HTML a MySQL. El detalle es que soy principiante y la verdad estoy un poco atorado en esta parte, ya que no tengo idea de como primero convertir esa tabla a un arreglo.

EL código que llevo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
<?php 

$htmlContent = file_get_contents("Ordenes.php");
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);
$header = $DOM -> getElementsByTagName('th');
$content = $DOM -> getElementsByTagName('td');

foreach($header as $nodeHeader){
    $headerArray [] = trim($nodeHeader -> textContent);
}
var_dump($headerArray);

$i = 0;
$j = 0;

    foreach($content as $nodeContent) 
    {
        $contentArray[$j][] = trim($nodeContent->textContent);
        $i = $i + 1;
        $j = $i % count($contentArray) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
    }
    var_dump($contentArray);
$titulo = 'Alta de Mantenimiento';
$urlPrim = 'index.php';
$urlSec = "Empleados.php";
$urlTer = 'Equipos.php';
$enlacePrim = 'Inicio';
$enlaceSec = 'Empleados';
$enlaceTer = 'Equipos';
include 'includes/templates/header.php';
?>

<nav class="tabs">
    <button type="submit" data-paso="1">Alta de Mantenimiento</button>
    <button type="submit" data-paso="2">Mantenimiento por equipos</button>
</nav>

<div id="paso-1" class="seccion-tab">
    <section>
        <form class="ordenes" method="$_POST" action="Ordenes.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Mantenimiento</legend>
                <div class="manto_contenedor_1">
                    <div class="manto_contenedor_sub">
                        <label>Seleccione un Equipo</label>
                            <input 
                            class="text" 
                            list="select_equipo"
                            name="equipo"
                            id="equipo">
                            <datalist id="select_equipo">
                            
                            </datalist>
                        <label>Herramienta Necesaria</label>
                            <textarea
                                class="text" 
                                name="herramienta"
                                id="herramienta">
                            </textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabla_añadir">
                        <h3>Añadir Actividades de Mantenimiento</h3>
                        <table class="tabla-empleado" id="tabla-empleado">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Depto Mantenimiento</th>
                                    <th>Frecuencia</th>
                                    <th>Actividad</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <td>
                                    <input 
                                    class="text-insertabla" 
                                    list="dptos-manto" 
                                    name="dpto" 
                                    id="dpto" 
                                    placeholder="Depto."
                                    >
                                    <datalist id="dptos-manto">

                                    </datalist>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input 
                                    class="text-insertabla" 
                                    list="select_frecuencias" 
                                    name="frecuencia" 
                                    id="frecuencia" 
                                    >
                                    <datalist id="select_frecuencias">

                                    </datalist>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input 
                                    class="text-insertabla"  
                                    name="actividad" 
                                    id="actividad" 
                                    >
                                </td>                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Comentarios</label>
                            <textarea 
                            class="text" 
                            name="coments"
                            id="coments">
                            </textarea>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="manto_contenedor_botones">
                        <input class= "boton" type="submit" value="Guardar">
                        <button type="button" class="boton" onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </section>

</div>
```

El código JS para agregar la fila es el siguiente:

```
function agregarFila(){
    document.getElementById("tabla-empleado").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><input class="text-insertabla" list="dptos-manto" name="dpto" id="dpto" placeholder="Depto."> <datalist id="dptos-manto"></datalist></td><td><input class="text-insertabla" list="select_frecuencias" name="frecuencia" id="frecuencia"><datalist id="select_frecuencias"></datalist></td><td><input class="text-insertabla" name="actividad" id="actividad"></td>';
}
```

Hasta ahora ya pude convertir la fila de los títulos en un arreglo, sin embargo no he podido convertir la tabla de contenido ya que el código ejecuta esta conversión durante la carga de la pagina y como el contenido esta en blanco no me genera ningún arreglo. Trate de incluir la ejecución de esta parte del código condicionándolo a que se ejecute cuando de click al botón de guardar, pero no logre realizarlo ya que aun así no me genera ningún arreglo. Esta es la parte donde estoy atorado ya que después de esto pretendo insertar a la BD a través de un FOR EACH. ¿Hay alguna manera mas sencilla de hacer lo que quiero hacer o estoy por el camino correcto?

Comment: Veo que tienes un formulario... Basta con agregarle al atributo `name` de cada campo unos corchetes al final, algo así: `name="frecuencia[]"`. Con esto obtienes los datos en un arreglo y lo puedes procesar en `php`.

Comment: Si las filas las agregas dinámicamente deberias enviarlas con ajax a tu PHP para que lo procese, sino PHP nunca las verá durante la carga inicial de la página, pero claro, no le veo el sentido a enviarlo en formato tabla de ese modo.